# Css dynamically rotate a div inside parent leaves gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotatetransform

I have a grid like structure full of rectangles, and currently using inline-flex to create this grid.

The rectangles are almost squares.

inside each rectangle i have a child div containing an image as background, and filling the parent div completely.

NOW!

When using javascript to rotate the inner div with image background to either 90 degrees or 270degrees when the inner div rotates, it leaves gaps on the edges between the inner div and the parent div.

I have tried using display = inline-block, block, grid (all), table(all) and everything else i can think of.

I even have a possible solution, however im not sure its the best and 100% full proof.

if the block width is 178px and the height is 160px before rotation, after rotating i switch the height and the width so the width becomes 160px and the height becomes 178px.

Now!! i noticed i i take the lowest width of 160px and minus the larger width of 178px, then divide it by 2 i get -9px.
if i make the position absolute, left -9px, the block fits perfectly left.
with the height i use Math,abs(-9), for position top and the block now fits flawlessly.

I'm not feeling comfortable with this solution.

How can i rotate my dive to fit perfectly.

```css
.flexParent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.parentBlock {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 178px;
  height: 160px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.parentBlock>.imageBlock {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  /*background: url('url/to/image.png');*/
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  width: 178px;
  height: 160px;
}

.parentBlock>.imageBlock.rotated {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-color: #ff0033;
  height: 178px;
  width: 160px;
  left: -9px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock rotated"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="imageBlock"></div>
  </div </div>
```

Comment: make all your element perfect square and it's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using absolute position, left:50%, top:50%, transform: translate(-50%, -50%); but must be done as below:

```
<style> div.parent{ position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); width:150px; height: 220px; background-color: red; } div.child { position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; transform-origin: center center; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg); height: 100px; width: 160px; background: limegreen; color: white; font-family: sans-serif; }
</style>
```

the order of the child css is very important. Unfortunetly for some reason i cant post answers here.. hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to rotate it 270 degrees?

I used `scale` to flib the X axis. and removed your new height and width

Also added scale Y, and Scale X+Y

```css
.flexParent{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    }

    .parentBlock{
    display:inline-flex;
    width:178px;
    height:160px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position:relative;
    }


    .parentBlock > .imageBlock{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:auto;
    background:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfGN0qNZ6SmotqZMfqcw3HtFx0auXMlYd-9jBwq8M2tPmPxwSWJA&s);
    width:178px;
    height:160px;
    }
    /*scale  X*/
    .parentBlock > .imageBlock.rotated{
    transform-origin:center center;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    background-color: #ff0033; 
    }
    /*scale  Y*/
    .parentBlock > .imageBlock.yScaled{
    transform-origin:center center;
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    background-color: #ff0033;  
    }
    /*scale both X and Y*/
    .parentBlock > .imageBlock.scaledBoth{
    transform-origin:center center;
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    background-color: #ff0033;     
    }
    /*Your original method*/
    .parentBlock > .imageBlock.rotateUp{
    transform-origin:center center;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    background-color: #ff0033;
    height:176px;
    width:158px;
    border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock rotated"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock yScaled"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock scaledBoth"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock"></div></div>
    <div class="parentBlock"><div class="imageBlock rotateUp"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Basically the rotation is dynamic, if the rotation lands on 0degrees or 180 degrees there is no issue, but for some odd reason its only with 90degrees and 270 degrees. the rotations work in increments of 90degrees... This approch seems to work on your code, i will try it with my code and let you know.   Just for interest why did you choose -1 for the scale? regards Antony

Comment: scale -1 is used to flib the axis. basically 2 becomes -2 etc. which flibs the box

Comment: if you need the same size, with your rotation method, I would create 1x1 boxes - then your issue would not happen

Comment: This an interesting and clean approach to the rotate function, i had no idea about the scale for rotation till now... My block sizes are also dynamically created so i have control over that, depends on device width and height.. i want to use your approach, is there a way to add transition effect to this scale approach for the rotation of the image, and have the rotation in both directions? Example: if i use css rotate(), i can use it with -270deg for a counter clock wise rotation or 270deg for a clockwise rotation and transition the transform,

Comment: giving both forward and revers animation effect, this effect is vital to my script. is there a way to have the same effect with the scale?

Comment: to be clear the effect doesnt have to look like it rotates/spins it must just do it thing in two directions, this will suffice my script then perfectly..

Comment: you can give them transition time, but i will not rotate without rotate. It will have a sort of `flib the card` transition.

Comment: Ok never mind, i figured it out.... it literally flips... looks like a 3d card flip.. this is a whole new approach for my needs i will give it a go...  Thank you for your input and time... Greets Antony (sorry i posted as you posted) Thank you again

Comment: @AntonyFalencikowski No worries - If this answer suffices to answer your question, then we would all appreciate if you were to accept the answer, this makes sure that everybody in the overview knows that this question has already been answered. also..... it gives me a little points.

Comment: i liked the result of your approach... what i decided to do is both... i got it worked out now.. basically i add a class which rotates the image div with a transform animation, giving me a spinning effect, then as it stops, i switch the class to give me the scale() approach to show the same image result with a perfect fit.. Its probably not ideal, but the best and cleanest option i've found this far, its also quick and not taxing on the device.. This was very educational for me.. thank you again... Regards Antony

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: <style>
    div.parent{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:150px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: red;
    }
      
    div.child {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 height: 100px;
 width: 160px;
    background: limegreen;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    </style>

Comment: the order of the child css is very important. Unfortunetly for some reason i cant post answers here..
hope this helps you.